# Single file mount to docker container is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume, mount

I'm trying to map one single file which is exist in the container with an edited copy which exist in my host by using docker-compose file. But it's not working. could someone please help me to fix this?

I'm not getting any error. But when i do a change on the file in host, its not reflecting inside the container.

### docker-compose entry

[image]

Both files in host and docker container have 777 permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue is. when mounting a single file and editing it, use the nano editor to edit the files or turn off swapfiles before using vim. when using vim, its creating a swapfile and replacing the existing one. therefore the file bind link is breaking. thats why the changes are not reflecting both sides.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the mount type as **bind** instead of volume.

```
st2stream: 
  image: ${ST2_IMAGE_REPO: -stackstorm/}st2stream: ${ST2_VERSION:-3.3.0} 
  restart: always 
  depends_on : 
    - st2api 
  networks: 
    - private 
  volumes: 
    - ./files/st2. docker.conf:/etc/st2/st2.docker.conf:ro 
    - ./files/st2.user.conf:/etc/st2/st2.user.conf:ro 
    - type: bind
      source: /opt/automation/projects/stackstorm/st2-docker/configs/st2stream/logging.docker.conf
      target: /etc/st2/logging.docker.conf
    - /opt/automation/projects/stackstorm/st2-logs:/var/log/st2:rw
```

Comment: Tried. But still same issue exist.